# Getting file lines named as variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file containing tickers, separated by a new line. So when the file is printed it looks like this:

```
 SPY

 QQQ
```

---

I am trying to use the Yahoo finance module to get the price for each ticker. However, I can not construct the `for` loop properly so that only the ticker(neither the brackets nor `\n`) are included. I need only the ticker to be declared (`var2 = Share('SPY') , var2 = Share('QQQ')`). Any help would be much appreciated. My current code is below

```
from yahoo_finance import Share

file = open('positions.txt', 'r')
result = [line.split(',') for line in file.readlines()]

for ticker in result:
    var = ticker
    var1 = str(ticker)
    #the yahoo finance functions are below
    var2 = Share(var1)
    print(var2.get_price())
```

Comment: Why are you using line.split(',') on each line in the file? I don't see any commas in the example file you posted so this would be not be necessary. Can you post an exact example of the positions.txt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely coming from the way you're parsing the `positions.txt` file. If it is really a text file of tickers separated by new lines, then readlines() should give you a list like the one directly below and (after some code cleanup), it works for me.

```
>>> result = ['SPY', 'QQQ']
>>> for ticker in result:
...     var2 = Share(ticker)
...     print(var2.get_price())
...
226.58
120.87
```

Here is what I would suggest, but I would need to see an example of your file to know for sure:

```
from yahoo_finance import Share

with open('positions.txt', 'r') as fp:
    result = fp.readlines()

for ticker in result:
    #the yahoo finance functions are below
    var2 = Share(ticker)
    print(var2.get_price())
```

Comment: You're welcome! When you receive an answer that you're happy with, you should click the accept button (near the top left corner of the answer) to indicate that this question has been answered.

Comment: @calico_ Please note that you have not `closed` the file after reading from it.